# Testing Laravel 4.2 with phpunit DB::table()->get() returns arrays not an objects

Tags: php, mysql, unit-testing, laravel-4, phpunit

I started adding unit / functional tests to legacy Laravel 4.2 webapp using phpunit and I'm seeing a weird error when `DB::table` is used.

Here is a very simple example, the test hits a controller method which calls `DB::table` then dies and dumps the result.

```
class ExternalFormTest extends TestCase {

    public function testGetExternalFormThankYouPage()
    {
        $response = $this->call('GET', 'test');
```

This is the controller method being hit.

```
public function getIndex()
{
    $results = DB::table('users')->get();
    dd($results);
```

This returns an array of arrays.

```
..array(12) {
  [0] =>
  array(74) {
    'id' =>
    int(1)
    [0] =>
    int(1)
    'account_number' =>
    int(1000)
    [1] =>
    int(1000)
    'account_admin' =>
    int(1)
```

But if I hit it with my browser.

And I get an array of objects...

```
array (size=12)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[1967]
      public 'id' => int 1
      public 'account_number' => int 1000
      public 'account_admin' => int 1
      public 'user_type' => int 1
```

This causes a bunch of errors throughout the App. Because the code expects to access properties (ie `$individual_result->id`) but the results are arrays.  I have tried this with sqlite in memory and normal MySql database.  Is this a bug or am I missing something about how Laravel returns results and/or how phpunit works.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

This is my phpunit.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit backupGlobals="false"
     backupStaticAttributes="false"
     bootstrap="bootstrap/autoload.php"
     colors="true"
     convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
     convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
     convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
     processIsolation="false"
     stopOnFailure="false"
     syntaxCheck="false"
>
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Application Test Suite">
            <directory>./app/tests/</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fetch mode is configured by the 'fetch' key in config/database.php. This should be `PDO::FETCH_CLASS`. Perhaps you have it set to `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` for the testing environment? As a workaround, you can try setting it directly in the controller to see if that would solve it:

```
public function getIndex()
{
    DB::connection()->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS);
    $results = DB::table('users')->get();
    dd($results);
}
```

If that works then it's just a matter of figuring out where it's getting set to `FETCH_ASSOC`.

Comment: This works.  Searching the project the only place PDO::FETCH_ASSOC or PDO::FETCH_CLASS show up is under vendor\doctrine, vendor\laravel, and vendor\symfony... so I don't think this is a local setup issue.  Thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

It should not matter if your are using on phpunit or inside your controllers. The behaviour is (supposed) to be the same.

Are you also using the **->get()** method on (I suppose) you controller to display the result on your browser?

As far as my knowledge with laravel goes, **->get()** is really supposed to return the results as an array.

Comment: As far as I can tell ->get() returns an array of objects, in typical use.  What I can't figure out is why it doesn't during testing.  From the docs "Like raw queries, the get method returns an array of results where each result is an instance of the PHP StdClass object. You may access each column's value by accessing the column as a property of the object:"